# Visual Studio 2017 publish sign tool error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel-addins

When I try to publish a C# Excel addin using Visual Studio 2017, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe. Sign Tool Error: Invalid option /fd

I have tried uninstalling all versions of Visual Studio then reinstalling Visual Studio 2017. I've also Googled the error and tried 3 or 4 suggested solutions.  None worked. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Eureka!!  I found it.  The problem was that when I uninstalled previous versions of visual studio going back to 2007, it did not uninstall the associated sign tool.  In 2007 /fd was not a valid option.  I manually deleted them and reinstalled visual studio.  It works fine now.

Comment: You actually need not to uninstall the old SignTool nor the old VisualStudio. You can make your new VisualStudio to use newer SignTool by changing the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` to most recent Windows SDK you have installed on your computer (just explore your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\` to find which SDKs do you have).

Answer (score 0):

You provided the flag "/fd" to the signing tool and it does not understand this. Try updating all your C# sharp programs and if this does not help try finding a setting where you can set arguments to the signing tool.

Comment: Visual studio adds the "/fd" automatically.  It's not in my code and I don't know where to find it.  I cannot find that option in arguments for my signing tool or publish options. 
 Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: then I have no clue at all

Comment: Thanks for trying.